# How to dump function output to a .txt file?

Tags: python

```
def example():
    print("hello, world!")

times = int(input("how many 'hello worlds'? "))
for c in range(times):
    example()
```

That's an example of what I'm trying to do.

If I type "3" in the input, I want my .txt file to contain the output of the function I created, which is:

```
hello, world!
hello, world!
hello, world!
```

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: is your question how to do it with python specifically? or how to redirect the output to a file in general?

Comment: There's a chapter "[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)" in the tutorial ... if that is your question.

Comment: You can use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can!
First you need to open the file, for which it is important that the program you are writing is in its folder. Here's how to do it:
`open ('the_file_name.txt', 'a')` ("a" as append). Of course, you haven't written in yet. You can do this by adding the file argentum to the print command: `print ('hello, world!', File = 'the_file_name.txt')`
Full code:

```
open ('the_file_name.txt', 'a')
def example ():
         print ("hello, world!", file = 'the_file_name.txt')

times = int (input ("how many 'hello worlds'?"))
for c in range (times):
     example ()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def example():
    print("hello, world!")

times = int(input("how many 'hello worlds'? "))
```

If you want to write a new file on each loop, open the file as 'w', so

```
output = ''
for c in range(times):
    output = f'{output}{example()}\n'
with open('./MyFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

Also, if you want to write without clear the file, open as 'a' that is append, so

```
with open('./MyFile.txt', 'a') as f:
```

But make sure that the file already exists

Comment: You didn't try this, or did you? If yes, I wonder what a strange version of Python you're running. (Even after your second edit this still is wrong. Please try it before posting an answer.)

Answer (score -1):

you can re-write the code a bit, but it should save the 'hello, world' text on a new line for now.

```
def example():
return "hello, world!"


times = int(input("how many 'hello worlds'? "))
data = []
for c in range(times):
    data.append(example())

file = open('finename.txt', 'w')
with file as f:
  for line in data:
    f.write(f'{line}\n')
```

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate creation of a list.